# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'list' and 'list'

Tags: python, operators

I am reading [Learning Python by Mark Lutz](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449355730).
 And it written in **Python Expression Operators** chapter:

> `x ^ y` - Bitwise XOR, set symmetric difference

After [brief googling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) on subject what is `symmetric difference` I expect `[1, 3]` as output from:

```
y = ['1', '2']
x = ['2', '3']
print x ^ y
```

but instead I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'list' and 'list'
```

What I didn't get? What is `^` actually for?

Comment: Use it with a `set`, not a `list`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation says, it's set symmetric difference, and python use `set` object for demonstrating the sets which support all the set operations.

```
>>> y = {'1', '2'}
>>> x = {'2', '3'}
>>> 
>>> x ^ y
set(['1', '3'])
```